having troube installing the latest vestion of flutter cannot extract
having troube installing the latest vestion of flutter cannot extracting  does anyone know what am I doing wrong [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/LzwpXwdr.png)
having troube installing the latest vestion of flutter cannot extracting  does anyone know what am I doing wrong

Can you please provide higher-resolution images? The images are not clear.

https://www.facebook.com/share/p/1BS7GtkS6TgkxkMS/

hi this is the link where I have higher-resolution images

Nope. Links to Facebook are not acceptable. Use the image button on the toolbar to upload them here, where they remain available for future users to see.

First, ensure the zip is downloaded in the ~/Downloads directory.
Then check the exact downloaded zip name:
ls ~/Downloads/

Once you have the name, use the following command to extract the contents to the ~/development/ directory:
# e.g. if name is: flutter_macos_arm64_3.24.3-stable.zip

unzip ~/Downloads/flutter_macos_arm64_3.24.3-stable.zip -d ~/development/

